# How to use onClickItem with react-responsive-carousel?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-responsive-carousel

I am trying to click images with using react-responsive-carousel. And on Click it should direct to the Link `onClickItem`. I have tried it with `<Link>` and `<a>`. Doesnt work.

```js
  const onClickItem = () => console.log('Item');
        <Carousel
              showStatus={false}
              showThumbs={false}
              autoPlay={true}
              infiniteLoop={true}
              swipeable={false}
              emulateTouch={true}
              //@ts-ignore
              animationHandler="fade"
              transitionTime={5000}
              onClickItem={onClickItem}
            >
              {banners.map((banner) => (
                <div className="block" key={banner.id}>
                  <Link href={banner.href}>
                    <a>
                      <div>
                        <Image src={banner.image} width={768} height={400} alt={'Banner image'} />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ))}
            </Carousel>
```

How to detect on Click with this component?

Answer (score 0):

1. define func on click

   const doClick = (bannerId) => {console.log(bannerId)}
2. add some func in your map

   `{banners.map((banner) => ( <div onClick={doClick(banner.id)} className="block" key={banner.id}> <Link href={banner.href}> <a> <div> <Image src={banner.image} width={768} height={400} alt={'Banner image'} /> </div> </a> </Link> </div> ))}`

Comment: I tried this doesn't work.

Comment: can you share error code?

Comment: Well, there is no error code. It just doesnt register the click event and no console.logs after being clicked.

Comment: can you share full code?